Reload function just... refuses to work for some reason?
Here is the code I use for my reload function:
if (Input.IsActionJustPressed("Reload") && clip < magSize || clip == 0)
{
  if (reloadTimer <= 0)
  {
    int availableToReload = magSize - clip;
    if (availableToReload > 0)
    {
      if (reserve >= availableToReload)
      {
        clip += availableToReload;
        reserve -= availableToReload;
      }
      else
      {
        clip += reserve;
        reserve = 0;
      }
    }
    reload.Visible = false;
    reloadTimer = 3f;
    isReloading = false;
  }
  else
  {
    isReloading = true;
    reload.Text = ("Reloading...");
    reload.Visible = true;
    reloadTimer -= (float)delta;
  }
}

When an empty reload happens (clip value is 0), it works without a hitch. But when I try a manual reload (clip still has ammo remaining, and I press R to reload), it just... doesn't? Weird thing is, when you do a manual reload, it detects that a reload is supposed to happen. It stops you from being able to shoot, an on-screen indicator appears, but it just... doesn't reload it?
Here's how it looks: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OVpiMhc30O7ZX_T_fKYUEI_lp-jWn73W/view?usp=sharing

Do you reduce the reloadTimer somewhere else, too? When does your UI getting updated? Just from the code alone I would assume, that the else tree should actually never be called, because clip is != 0 after the first run.

I sat there and asked my self how your code is even working. Now I think I understand it.
your reloadTimer is set to 3 in the beginning. If the clip is empty it will arrive in the else part of your second if statement until reloadTimer <= 0. Then it will actually reload.
The problem is, that you will not pass through the first if statement, if you reload manually, because the reload Button is just pressed the first time. So you arrive in the else statement in the first iteration after clicking reload and then in the second duration ActionJustPressed("Reload") will return false and clip == 0 is false also.
So you have to seperate the reloadTimer and the execute command of the reload:
//if he should reload execute your code
if (isReloading)
{
  if (reloadTimer <= 0)
  {
    int availableToReload = magSize - clip;
    if (availableToReload > 0)
    {
      if (reserve >= availableToReload)
      {
        clip += availableToReload;
        reserve -= availableToReload;
      }
      else
      {
        clip += reserve;
        reserve = 0;
      }
    }
    reload.Visible = false;
    reloadTimer = 3f;
    isReloading = false;
  }
  else
  {
    reload.Text = ("Reloading...");
    reload.Visible = true;
    reloadTimer -= (float)delta;
  }
}

//If Reload is pressed or the clip is empty trigger isReloading
if (Input.IsActionJustPressed("Reload") && clip < magSize || clip == 0)
{
    if (isReloading = false)
        isReloading = true; //Trigger the reloading
}

